# $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ embedding into continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For each $t$, let $u(t):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We can think of this as
$$u(t)(x) = u(t,x)$$
for $x \in \Omega.$

If $\nabla u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ (this is the spatial gradient) can I say anything about $u$? I'd like to say $u$ is continuous in time or something like that?

Comment: You mean $u=u(t,x)$, $t\in (0,T)$, $x\in \Omega$? I think a clarification in the notation is required.

Comment: Yes sorry my old notation was wrong.

Comment: Without any additional hyphotesis nothing can be said about the behavior in time. Note in these examples, $u(t,x)=f(t)\, g(x)$, with $\nabla g \in L^\infty$ and $f$ a bounded function.